# Update Pipeline Run Retention

Tags: azure-pipelines

I'm looking to update a lease in a multi-stage pipeline, and my tasks are configured as per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/run-retention?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell#example-updating-the-retention-window-for-a-multi-stage-pipeline-based-on-stage-success)

My task fails with the below error

```
##[error]Invoke-RestMethod : 
{"count":1,"value":{"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'PATCH'."}}
```

The lease is created fine in the `Build` stage - I just can't *update* it in a later stage

I'm using the latest API version, where there's clearly a [PATCH update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/leases/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2)

What am I doing wrong here, and has anyone managed to get this to work?

I've seen [this issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/12858), but the code is the same as the docs - it still errors out on me

Ran the same tasks as the docs, but get an error as described above

Comment: Can you share the code you're using at the moment? Prevents us from having to piece together what you're doing.

Comment: Are you connecting to Azure DevOps (cloud) or Azure DevOps Server? If Server, which version? Are you using YAML pipelines or a separate "UI based" Release pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample in the doc: [Example: Updating the retention window for a multi-stage pipeline based on stage success](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/run-retention?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell#example-updating-the-retention-window-for-a-multi-stage-pipeline-based-on-stage-success) is using [cross-stage variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#use-outputs-in-a-different-stage) to pass the newLeaseId to the next stage.

When the variables of the previous stage are not passed to the next stage, the error you encountered will occur.

I can reproduce the same issue.

[image]

To solve the issue, you need to check the cross stage variable settings.

You need to set **dependsOn** in the next stage and use the following format to reference the output variables of the previous stage:

`$[ stageDependencies.stagename.jobname.outputs['taskname.MyVar'] ]`

```
stages:
- stage: One
  jobs:
  - job: A
    steps:
    - task: MyTask@1  # this step generates the output variable
      name: ProduceVar  # because we're going to depend on it, we need to name the step

- stage: Two
  dependsOn:
  - One
  jobs:
  - job: B
    variables:
      # map the output variable from A into this job
      varFromA: $[ stageDependencies.One.A.outputs['ProduceVar.MyVar'] ]
```

For example:

```
stages:
- stage: previousstagename
  jobs:
     - job: previousjobname
       steps:
         - task: PowerShell@2
           name: RetainOnSuccess
           displayName: Retain on Success
           inputs:
            failOnStderr: true
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: |
               $contentType = "application/json";
               $headers = @{ Authorization = 'Bearer $(System.AccessToken)' };
               $rawRequest = @{ daysValid = 365; definitionId = $(System.DefinitionId); ownerId = 'User:$(Build.RequestedForId)'; protectPipeline = $false; runId = $(Build.BuildId) };
               $request = ConvertTo-Json @($rawRequest);
               $uri = "$(System.CollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/build/retention/leases?api-version=6.0-preview.1";
               $newLease = Invoke-RestMethod -uri $uri -method POST -Headers $headers -ContentType $contentType -Body $request;
               $newLeaseId = $newLease.Value[0].LeaseId
               echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=newLeaseId;isOutput=true]$newLeaseId";
   
- stage: Release
  dependsOn: previousstagename
  jobs:
  - job: default
    variables:
    - name: NewLeaseId
      value: $[ stageDependencies.previousstagename.previousjobname.outputs['RetainOnSuccess.newLeaseId']]
    steps:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      condition: and(succeeded(), not(canceled()))
      name: RetainOnSuccess
      displayName: Retain on Success
      inputs:
        failOnStderr: true
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          $contentType = "application/json";
          $headers = @{ Authorization = 'Bearer $(System.AccessToken)' };
          $rawRequest = @{ daysValid = 365 };
          $request = ConvertTo-Json $rawRequest;
          $uri = "$(System.CollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/build/retention/leases/$(newLeaseId)?api-version=7.1-preview.2";
          echo $uri;
          echo $(NewLeaseId);
          Invoke-RestMethod -uri $uri -method PATCH -Headers $headers -ContentType $contentType -Body $request;
```

**Result:**

[image]